# Cannot import Jelastic Manifest with cURL command using two -H parameters

Tags: jelastic

I'm trying to create a Jelastic Manifest with a cURL command inside it. When I import it, it gives me an error but unfortunately I have no access to the console (disabled by the provider).

The command is the following :
`curl -X POST <my_url> -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" -d "{}"`

Some additionnal information :

- The URL is correct 100%
- The token does not contain any special characters : Only upper/lowercase characters and numbers
- The command is run successfully from the command line
- If I remove the first `-H` parameter, I can import my manifest. Same if I remove the second `-H` parameter and keep the first one

My guess is that, somehow, having two `-H` is not considered as valid but I don't know why. Any ideas ?

EDIT : A screenshot of the error shown on the platform

[image]

Comment: Multiple '-H' may be used in curl. Presumably, the error may be in the data passed via '-d'. Maybe something needs to be escaped if executed from the console.
You may also try to use a file when sending data via curl as --data "@path_to_file".
In such a case there will be no problems with escaping JSON.
Due to the fact that you have no access to the console, please specify your Hosting provider name and your user ID (without pointing an email) to analyze the matter more thoroughly on our side.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Jelastic, however the data I pass in the "-d" is empty because I thought the same. So I send an empty JSON like "{}" but it seems that the error always occurs. I'm posting an answer soon since the provider answered me.

Comment: Hey, @Jacks! Could you, please, clarify, were able to resolve this problem with the hosting provider? If not, let us know your hosting provider and user ID we will check!

Comment: Hey @Jelastic, sorry for the long wait ! The problem is the following : `Bad indentation of a sequence entry` when using the JPS editor (instead of importing a .yaml file). The editor / interpreter thinks I am beginning a list when setting "Content-Type : xxx" because of the ":" and spaces around it. I have been able to start my script by removing the spaces around, so let me know if this is the correct answer or if you think a fix is needed by your side, thanks !

Comment: Hello, @Jacks! We believe that it works as expected and you have just missed quotes for that parameter and that's why space removing helps you. But to be 100% sure we have to see your manifest.

Comment: @Jelastic The cURL command I provided in my question is exactly the same as the one in my manifest. Unfortunately I cannot share with you the manifest, but I have edited my question to add a screenshot of the error as show on the platform (in the JPS editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "two -H parameters" wasn't a root cause in your question.

The thing is that the YAML gets the data you sent as a key/value array (dictionary).

In your example it would be:

`curl -s -X POST https://test.com -H "Content-Type` - as a key,

and

`application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xx" -d "{\"Key\":\"Value\"}"` - as a value.

If you need an array of strings the YAML may be as this

```
cmd [cp]:
  - 'curl -s -X POST https://test.com -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xx" -d "{\"Key\":\"Value\"}"'
```

If you need a multi-line string it should look like this

```
cmd [cp]: |
  curl -s -X POST https://test.com -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xx" -d "{\"Key\":\"Value\"}"
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure to understand your answer correctly : So my cURL command is interpreted as a key/value array right ? And wrapping it around quotes would solve the problem ? Sorry to ask that, but isn't it kind of a "bug" that it interprets my command as a dictionnary even if I have my parameters in double-quotes ? Or did I miss something ? Thank you anyway for your time !

Comment: JPS manifest can be saved in JSON or YAML format. In your current case, the YAML format was used and therefore you need to follow the YAML specification.

In the case of the curl command, it is defined as key/value because there is a colon followed by the space in your example: https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#:%20mapping%20value/

Comment: The cmd action in the JPS manifest can take a string or a sequence of strings as the input. In order for the YAML parser not to accept special character sequences, they need to be escaped in accordance with the documentation: https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id872840  or wrap the value in single (https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id905860) or double quotes (https://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id904245).

Comment: It is most convenient to use multi-line strings since they almost do not need to be escaped or wrapped (the second example in our answer for multi-line string).

Some more specific details you may also find via this link https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html#gotchas

A similar problem is a little bit more described there.

Though we'd like to mention that YAML is not the Jelastic product itself.